# One table to rule them all, or thousand smaller?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have 10k users in my mySQL DB, for every user i need to store last 500 events.
Please, advice me, how should i design my DB? One MegaEventsTable or dedicated table for every user? 
Pros of many small tables:
 - i can fast pick, for example, 50 events by type from 500 entries than from 500*10k entries.
 - its is faster get top 500 entries, and kill all other entries in table for this user
 - i can shard my entries database some time in future
Contras:
 - i feel that 10k tables is HORRIBLE idea (and what if there will be 100K)

Comment: Voting to move to DBA.SE, where it has been cross-posted: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121326/one-table-to-rule-them-all-or-thousand-smaller

Comment: And please, don't do that (posting the same question in many sites). One question, in one site, is enough.

Comment: @ypercube sorry, just there is mush more people here than on DBA. Should i delete my post on DBA?

Comment: I don't think you can delete it, now that it has an answer. You can flag one of your questions for *"in need for moderator intervention"* and explain what happened and what you want (either delete this or the dba one or merge the 2, so both answers stay).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are almost no situations where you should have one table for each user.  There are numerous reasons why.  Here are some:

- MySQL is less efficient with small tables than with larger tables.  The smaller tables will occupy more space because of partially filled pages.
- You cannot use `userId` as a foreign key reference, because it refers to multiple tables.
- You cannot easily change the structure of the `Users` table.  You have to change thousands of them.
- You can use indexes and partitions to increase the speed of your queries.
- Databases are designed to handle large amounts of data, and 10,000 rows is not a large amount of data.